# Calling one function in another and passing it id, react + redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

In React itself, I have the function `getTodos()`, in which it calls another function`getTodo()`. It passes `res.data[0].id` to the `getTodo()` function.

**React**

Demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qvsjrz

Code below:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      todos: [],
      todo: {}
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getTodos()
  }

  getTodos = () => {
    axios({
        url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos',
        method: 'GET'
    })
    .then(res => {
      this.setState({
        todos: res.data,
      }, () => this.getTodo(res.data[0].id))
    })  
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  };

  getTodo = (todoId) => {
    axios({
      url: `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${todoId}`,
      method: 'GET'
    })
    .then(res => {
      this.setState({
        todo: res.data
      })
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);

    })
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.todo);
    return (
      <div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The above code tries to convert to react + redux.

**React + redux**

In actions, I declared two functions `getTodo` and`getTodos`. Could someone advise me on how to call the `getTodo` function in the`getTodos` function by passing the `getTodo` id function?

Demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ewpquh?file=actions%2Findex.js

**actions**

```
   import axios from 'axios';

    export const GET_TODOS = 'GET_TODOS';
    export const FETCH_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_SUCCESS';
    export const FETCH_FAILURE = 'FETCH_FAILURE';

    export const getTodos = () => 
     dispatch => {

  return axios({
      url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos',
      method: 'GET',
    })
    .then(({data})=> {
      console.log(data);

      dispatch({type: GET_TODOS, payload:{
        data 
      }});   
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);

      dispatch({type: FETCH_FAILURE})
    });
};

    export const getTodo = () => 
    dispatch => {


  return axios({
      url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos',
      method: 'GET',
    })
    .then(({data})=> {
      console.log(data);

      dispatch({type: GET_TODOS, payload:{
        data 
      }});   
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);

      dispatch({type: FETCH_FAILURE})
    });
};
```

**Todos**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {getTodos} from '../.././actions';

class Todos extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getTodos(); 
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.props.todos.map(todo => {
        return <li key={todo.id}>
                  {todo.title}
               </li>
         })}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  console.log(state.todos);
  const { todos } = state;

  return {
    todos
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  getTodos: () => dispatch(getTodos())
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Todos);
```

**reducers**

```
import {GET_TODOS} from '../../actions';

const initialState = {
  todos: []
};

const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'GET_TODOS':
      return {
        ...state,
        todos: action.payload.data
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default rootReducer;
```

**store**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

export default store;
```

Comment: Instead of complicating your actions, I'd suggest, you add another prop as 'getTodo' that takes in the ID as input and dispatches 'getTodo' action with that ID.

Comment: @pritam and how do you put this `getTodo` inside` getTodos`? Do just componentDidMount (this.props.getTodos, this.props.getTodo (this.props.id)). `Id` fetch directly from the state?

Comment: added answer with sandbox link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of over-complicating your actions, you should have separate action types for different APIs.

1. GET_TODOS - For /todos API
2. GET_TO - For /todos/ API

To add `getTodo` method with ID, this is how I solved it -

1. For each `li` tag, add an `onClick` that calls your `getTodo` API. (This is done as an example for the sake of adding `getTodo` in the workflow.

```js
    return <li key={todo.id} onClick={() => this.handleClick(todo.id)}>
```

2. Add `handleClick` which calls `getTodo` method from props.

   - First add `getTodo` in your components `mapDispatchToProps`:

```js
    import { getTodo, getTodos} from '../.././actions';

    const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
      getTodos: () => dispatch(getTodos()),
      getTodo: id => dispatch(getTodo(id))
    });
```

- Add `handleClick` -

```js
  handleClick = id => {
    this.props.getTodo(id).then(() => {
      console.log(`You Clicked: ${JSON.stringify(this.props.todo)}`)
    })
  }
```

3. Update your `getTodo` action to take ID as input:

> NOTE: The added GET_TODO type

```js
export const getTodo = (id) => dispatch => {

  return axios({
      url: `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${id}`,
      method: 'GET',
    })
    .then(({data})=> {
      // console.log(data);
      dispatch({type: GET_TODO, payload: data});   
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);

      dispatch({type: FETCH_FAILURE})
    });
};
```

4. Separate out your reducers into `todos` and `todo` and use `combineReducers` from `redux` package -

```js
const todos = (state = [], action) => {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch(type) {
    case 'GET_TODOS':
      return payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const todo = (state = {}, action) => {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch(type) {
    case 'GET_TODO':
      return payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({todos, todo});
```

5. Run the app and click on any item in the todo list. Console log for the clicked todo item is shown when API response for that ID is fetched.

The live sandbox is available here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ndkasm

Comment: Thanks. But I have a problem. I have to call function `getTodo` inside `componentDidMount()` and pass `this.getTodo(res.data[0].id)`.  Is it possible?

Comment: It is possible to do that, but the wait time will be increased. Check the updated implementation of 'componentDidMount()' at the same sandbox link.