# Converting functions from pure react to redux react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

In pure react, I have written a function that I call in `componentDidMount ()`:

```
  getTasks = (userId, query, statusTask, pageNumber) => {
    let check = {};
    axios({
      url: `/api/v1/beta/${userId}`,
      method: 'GET'
    })
      .then(res => {
        check = res.data;

        if (res.data) {
          this.setState({
            checkRunning: res.data,
            checkRunningId: res.data.id
          });
          this.utilizeTimes(res.data.task_id);
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      })
      .then(() => {
        const params = {
          sort: 'name'
        };

        if (query) {
          params['filter[qwp]'] = query;
          if (this.state.tasks[0]) {
            this.setState({
              selectedId: this.state.tasks[0].id,
              selectedTabId: this.state.tasks[0].id
            });
          }
        }

        axios({
          url: '/api/v1//tasks',
          method: 'GET',
          params
        })
          .then(res => {
            if (res.status === 200 && res.data) {
              this.setState({
                tasks: res.data,
                lengthArrayTasks: parseInt(res.headers['x-pagination-total-count'])
              });

              if (!check && res.data && res.data[0]) {
                this.setState({
                  selectedTabId: res.data[0].id,
                });

                this.load(res.data[0].id);
              }

              let myArrayTasks = [];
              myArrayTasks = res.data;
              let findObject = myArrayTasks.find(task => task.id === this.state.runningTimerTask.id);

              if (
                !findObject &&
                this.state.runningTimerTask &&
                this.state.runningTimerTask.id &&
                this.state.query === ''
              ) {
                this.setState({
                  tasks: [this.state.runningTimerTask, ...myArrayTasks]
                });
              }
            }
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
          });
      });
  };
```

I am trying to rewrite it to redux, but with poor results. First it makes one request `/ api / v1 / beta / $ {userId}`, writes the answer in the variable `check`. `check` passes to the next`then`. In the next `then` carries out the request '/ api / v1 // tasks' Can somebody help me? I am asking for some tips. Is this somehow complicated?

So far, I've managed to create something like this:

**store**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

export default store;
```

**actions**

```
export const RUNNING_TIMER = 'RUNNING_TIMER';
export const GET_TASKS = 'GET_TASKS';
export const FETCH_FAILURE = 'FETCH_FAILURE';

export const runningTimer = (userId, query, statusTask, pageNumber) => dispatch => {
  console.log(userId);
  axios({
    url: `/api/v1/beta/${userId}`,
    method: 'GET'
  })
    .then(({ data }) => {
      dispatch({
        type: RUNNING_TIMER,
        payload: data
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);

      dispatch({ type: FETCH_FAILURE });
    })
    .then(() => {
      const params = {
        sort: 'name'
      };

      axios({
        url: '/api/v1//tasks',
        method: 'GET',
        params
      })
        .then(({ data }) => {
            dispatch({
                type: GET_TASKS,
                payload: data
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    });
};
```

**reducer**

```
import { RUNNING_TIMER, GET_TASKS } from '../actions';

const isRunningTimer = (state = {}, action) => {
  const { type, payload } = action;
  switch (type) {
    case RUNNING_TIMER:
      return {
        checkRunningTimer: payload,
        checkRunningTimerId: payload && payload.id ? payload.id : null
      };
      break;
      case GET_TASKS:
      return {
        tasks: payload,
        lengthArrayTasks: parseInt(action.headers['x-pagination-total-count'])
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({ isRunningTimer });

export default rootReducer;
```

**App**

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React'
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.runningTimer();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const { isRunningTimer } = state;

  return {
    isRunningTimer
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  runningTimer: (userId, query, statusTask, pageNumber) => dispatch(runningTimer()),
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App);
```

Comment: You might find this answer useful. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58216027/1263904
It also has a sandbox to play around.

Comment: @pritam Can we talk on chat?

Comment: What is runningTimer in `runningTimer: (userId, query, statusTask, pageNumber) => dispatch(runningTimer()),` the `runintTimer()` part?

Comment: @HMR should be `const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  runningTimer: (userId, query, statusTask, pageNumber) => dispatch(runningTimer(userId, query, statusTask, pageNumber))
});`

Comment: @HMR runningTimer it is action

Comment: But you call it with `runningTimer()`, the action is `export const runningTimer = (userId, query, statusTask, pageNumber) => dispatch => {` So what `runnintTimer()` does is that it returns `dispatch => {` where userId, query, statusTask, pageNumber are all undefined.

Comment: @HMR I call runningTimer() in another function and take userId

Comment: Your reducer should always return the same "shape" of state. It looks the intended state should have 4 properties: ```checkRunningTimer```, ```checkRunningTimerId```, ```tasks```, and ```lengthArrayTasks```.
However, your reducer only ever returns 2 of the 4 of those properties when an action is called, it should always return all 4, even if those states didn't change.

Comment: So for ```RUNNING_TIMER```, the reducer should return:
          ```return {
            checkRunningTimer: payload,
            checkRunningTimerId: payload && payload.id ? payload.id : null,
            tasks: state.tasks,
            lengthArrayTasks: state.lengthArrayTasks
          };```

Use whatever syntactic sugar you want

Comment: @ZekeHernandez My main problem: How  break two `.then` in the `getTasks` function?

Comment: @HMR  My main problem: How break two .then in the getTasks function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Number 1 Consider your state design.

I find it useful to consider what the state object would look like at a given point in time.

Here is an example of initialState used in an application of mine.

```
const initialState = {
        grocers: null,
        coords: {
            latitude: 37.785,
            longitude: -122.406
        }

    };
```

This is injected at the createStore.

Breaking down your application state object/properties, should assist you in making your actions simpler as well.

## Number 2

Consider breaking down your actions.

My thoughts, decouple the action code, <del>at the .then</del> at the second .then .(Consider saving the results somewhere in a user: object)

```
        .then(response => {
          const data = response.data.user;
          setUsers(data);})
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ' + error.message);
        })

    function setUsers(data){
        dispatch({
            type: FETCH_USERS,
            payload: data
        });
    }
```

This refers to the S in SOLID design principles. Single Responsibility Principle.

https://devopedia.org/solid-design-principles

## Number 3

Consider this, if the 'getUser' info fetch fails.

Having the process/response separated will allow the application to be debugged more cleanly. In example,  the user api failed or the getTask api failed, etc.

---

More resources on redux.
https://redux.js.org/introduction/learning-resources#thinking-in-redux

Comment: Look at my component in pure Rect. I can't decouple `.then`

Comment: You can separate at the second .then, I have inserted an example to wrap and 'close' that action up. Name and seperate those actions using your own thoughts.

Answer (score 3):

Extending previous answer from @Cullen, this is what I did:

1. Since you already have a action to GET_TODOS, just make the action creator for `runningTimer` to do one and only one thing - make API call to `/api/v1/beta/<userId>` and dispatch respective actions.

```js
export const runningTimer = (
  userId,
  query,
  statusTask,
  pageNumber
) => dispatch => {
  return axios({
    url: `/api/v1/beta/${userId}`,
    method: "GET"
  })
    .then(({ data }) => {
      dispatch({
        type: RUNNING_TIMER,
        payload: data
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);

      dispatch({ type: FETCH_FAILURE });
    });
};
```

2. Update props of your app component to read store data.

```js
...
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const { isRunningTimer, todos, todo } = state;

  return {
    todos,
    todo,
    isRunningTimer,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  getTodos: () => dispatch(getTodos()),
  getTodo: id => dispatch(getTodo(id)),
  runningTimer: (userId, query, statusTask, pageNumber) => dispatch(runningTimer(userId)),
});
...
```

3. Update the implementation of `componentDidMount` to dispatch `isRunningTimer` -

```js
componentDidMount() {
...
    // call with userId 1
    this.props.runningTimer(1).then(() => {
      console.log(this.props);

          // additional params for getTasks
      const params = {
        sort: 'name'
      };

      // another call for getTodos with names sorted
      this.props.getTodos(params);
    });
...
```

> Note: You need to update your `getTodos` action to take in an optional `params` arguments (which is initialized to empty object if not passed).

Hope this helps you.

Live sandbox for this is present here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-redux-more-actions

Comment: Look at my function in pure React is complicated. Compare your function with mu function in pure react. In your function doesn't have a few elements

Comment: Well, pls don't expect a full answer. We guys can give you insights on how to do a thing, take a pen and paper and simplify your workflow. You'll get better understanding of how you should go about adding those missing pieces. If you'd like to chat, do let me know how and when you'd want to.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [React-boilerplate](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate). Great boilerplate for react and redux. They use `redux-saga` and `redux-hooks` as well.