# how to dispatch a action to save data in store in next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

what i want to do is dispatch an action in my set interval function and not in get initial props and save my data in store and how to get that data back from store in react app it was simple just import action form action file and call like this  `this.props.actionName()` but how do i do this in next and to get data from store we map state to props how can it be done in next thanks here my function which i want to implement in

```
this.fetchCryptoData().then(data => {
       var Keys = Object.keys(data.DISPLAY);
        this.setState(
          {
            crypto_head_coins: Keys
          },
          () => {
            //   // this.props.update_array([]); // update_array() is my action i haven't imported it
            let rate_updated = [true, true, true, true]; // i want my store updated_array data here
            for (let i = 0; i < this.state.crypto_head_coins.length; i++) {
             //my code here
            // this.props.store.dispatch(update_rate_array(rate_updated)) //it says cant read property
           // of dispatch of undefined 
            // i want to dispatch my action here not in getinitialprops
                    this.setState({ rate_updated });
                  }
                );
              });
```

Comment: this is not set interval but it is in set interval

Comment: To begin with, you need to connect your component. https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use NextJS sometimes, It is the same as a Create-React-App essentially.

I just noticed your question does not include 'React-Redux', You will need to install/save 'React-Redux' and 'Redux' to use connect/dispatch, etc. I have a [sample boilerplate on Github](https://github.com/StaticSpark/ReactReduxStarterExampleCode/blob/master/README.md).

Another missing piece for converting this into an action.. is perhaps redux-thunk, to handle promises.(Try without it first.)

More information on redux-thunk here.
https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk

You are setting state twice(once in the callback of another), which is going to cause multiple re-renders. (Unless ShouldComponentUpdate is implemented) Might want to re-consider this design.

## Implement your MapDispatch to Props

After doing so you can simplify the line calling it, like the below using destructing.

```
// this.props.store.dispatch(update_rate_array(rate_updated)) //it says cant read property

let update_rate_array = {this.props}

update_rate_array(rate_updated)
```

You should implement your MapDispatchToProps removing some complexity in the naming and calling.

I have uploaded [some simple examples to Github](https://github.com/StaticSpark/ReactReduxStarterExampleCode/blob/master/src/components/profile.js), and there is also [an identical related CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactreduxstarterexamplecode-97fnm).

## To receive your updated information from State, use MapStateToProps.

[Example here](https://github.com/StaticSpark/ReactReduxStarterExampleCode/blob/master/src/pages/about.js).

Comment: I have updated the answer, with an example of mapStateToProps. When props update, the page will re-render.

Comment: you are a life saver thanks a lot i have checked out every medium post and they all use this in getinitialprops not a single one use like creat-react-app if you would not have answered idk how i was going to know this

Comment: i'm setting a default value in my reducer but my state getting value of foo why is that

Comment: this is my reducer const initialState = [true, true, true, true];

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  //   console.log(action.payload);
  switch (action.type) {
    case "UPDATE_RATE_ARRAY":
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

Comment: can u see my github repo https://github.com/naveenkash/Forex/tree/development redux why it's value getting set foo i'll be thankfull

Comment: and i'm calling my action in crypto_head.js

Comment: This is another question, my example is only updating a string value. What does your console.log show? I almost suggest breaking down your state, updating an array may be counterintuitive. Causing challenges when debugging later. Also.. consider setting intial state in your createStore.

Comment: first it should be initial state value but it's foo

Comment: Initial State, should be set here, https://github.com/naveenkash/Forex/blob/development/redux/index.js..

Consider drawing up your state first, look at my previous answer on SO.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58234442/converting-functions-from-pure-react-to-redux-react/58260897#58260897

If these help.. please accept and upvote both.

Comment: it is an empty object right now what it should set to?

Comment: Depends on how your project works, does there need to be any value initially? If not use null, or empty array for most state properties. Better to have the state structure in the initialize though, prior to creating actions and reducers to help you think things through.